# Why i cant retrive a thing that is in the Hashtable?

Tags: c, file, hashtable

I have this code and the problem i am having is when i manualy insert a word and try to retreive it works but when i insert with this function doesn't work, the file i ma using it is a .txt with a word in each line and has arround like 59000 words. I can get the last word witch it is "ZULUS" but can get anyone more can't figure this out.

```
void readwords(HashTable H,char *filename){
    char word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t lineLength = 0;

    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to open the file.\n");
        return;
    }
    // Read words from the file and insert them into the hash table
   while (getline(&line, &lineLength, file) != -1) {
        // Remove leading spaces
        char *trimmedLine = line + strspn(line, " \t");

        // Extract words from the line
        char *token = strtok(trimmedLine, " \t\n");
        while (token != NULL) {
            strcpy(word,token);
            // Copy the word without leading spaces
            Insert(word, H);
            // Get the next word
            token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        }
        
    }
    
    fclose(file);
}
```

this is my hash.c with the implementation of the hash table, this what i think would work but don't know much about it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "hash.h"

#define Error(Str) FatalError(Str)
#define FatalError(Str) fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", Str), exit(1)

#define MinTableSize (10)

enum KindOfEntry { Legitimate, Empty, Deleted };

typedef char* ElementType; // Assuming ElementType is a string

struct HashEntry {
    ElementType Element;
    enum KindOfEntry Info;
};

typedef struct HashEntry Cell;

/* Cell *TheCells will be an array of */
/* HashEntry cells, allocated later */
struct HashTbl {
    int Occupados;
    int TableSize;
    Cell* TheCells;
};





bool IsPrime(int num) {
    if (num <= 1)
        return false;

    for (int i = 2; i * i <= num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

static int NextPrime(int N) {
    if (N <= 1)
        return 2;

    int prime = N;
    bool found = false;

    while (!found) {
        prime++;
        if (IsPrime(prime))
            found = true;
    }

    return prime;
}



Index Hash( const char *Key, int TableSize ){
    unsigned int HashVal = 0;
    while( *Key != '\0' )
    HashVal = ( HashVal << 5 ) + *Key++;    
    return HashVal%TableSize;
}

HashTable InitializeTable(int TableSize) {
    HashTable H;
    int i;

    if (TableSize < MinTableSize) {
        Error("Table size too small");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Allocate table */
    H = malloc(sizeof(struct HashTbl));
    if (H == NULL)
        FatalError("Out of space!!!");

    H->TableSize = TableSize;


    /* Allocate array of Cells */
    H->TheCells = malloc(sizeof(Cell) * H->TableSize);
    if (H->TheCells == NULL)
        FatalError("Out of space!!!");

    for (i = 0; i < H->TableSize; i++)
        H->TheCells[i].Info = Empty;

    return H;
}

Position Find( ElementType Key, HashTable H ){
    Position CurrentPos;
    int CollisionNum;
    CollisionNum = 0;
    CurrentPos = Hash( Key, H->TableSize );
    while( H->TheCells[ CurrentPos ].Info != Empty && strcmp(H->TheCells[CurrentPos].Element, Key) != 0){
            CurrentPos += 2 * ++CollisionNum - 1;
        if( CurrentPos >= H->TableSize )
            CurrentPos -= H->TableSize;
    }
    return CurrentPos;
}
HashTable Rehash(HashTable H) {
    int i, OldSize;
    Cell* OldCells;

    OldCells = H->TheCells;
    OldSize = H->TableSize;

    /* Get a new, empty table */
    H = InitializeTable(2 * OldSize);

    /* Scan through the old table, reinserting into the new */
    for (i = 0; i < OldSize; i++)
        if (OldCells[i].Info == Legitimate)
            Insert(OldCells[i].Element, H);

    free(OldCells);

    return H;
}

void Insert(ElementType Key, HashTable H) {
     Position Pos;
    Pos = Find( Key, H );
    if( H->TheCells[ Pos ].Info != Legitimate ){
        H->TheCells[ Pos ].Info = Legitimate;
        H->TheCells[Pos].Element = strdup(Key);
        H->Occupados++;
    }
}


float LoadFactor(HashTable H) {
    return (float)H->Occupados / H->TableSize;
}


ElementType Retrieve(Position P, HashTable H) {
    return H->TheCells[P].Element;
}

void DestroyTable(HashTable H) {
    free(H->TheCells);
    free(H);
}
```

this is the hash.h

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#ifndef _Hash_H
#define _Hash_H

typedef char* ElementType; // Assuming ElementType is a string

typedef struct HashTbl *HashTable;
typedef unsigned int Index;
typedef Index Position;

HashTable InitializeTable(int TableSize);
void DestroyTable(HashTable H);
Position Find(ElementType Key, HashTable H);
void Insert(ElementType Key, HashTable H);
float LoadFactor(HashTable H);
HashTable Rehash(HashTable H);
ElementType Retrieve(Position P, HashTable H);
#endif  // HASH_H
/* Routines such as Delete are MakeEmpty are omitted */

/* END */
```

and this is the main i am running

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    
    char filename[] = "corncob_caps_2023.txt";
    char filename2[] = "boggle0.txt"; 
    int tableSize = 60000; 
   

    HashTable words = InitializeTable(tableSize);
    readwords(words,filename);
    printf("%s",Retrieve(Find("ZULUS",words),words));
    return 0;
}
```

the input it is something like this

```
AARDVARK
AARDWOLF
AARON
ABACK
ABACUS
ABAFT
ABALONE
ABANDON
ABANDONED
ABANDONMENT
```

made some changes but still not working

Comment: @L1nK Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Insert(word, H) puts a pointer to a local variable in the table. You need to make a copy of the string.

Comment: `Element != Key` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Do not typedef pointers as it hides common problems like this. Strings are arrays and need to use string functions rather than assignments or equality tests.

Comment: @stark whats the best way to solve the copy problem?

Comment: @L1nK the best way for the copy problem: 1. read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book. 2. look into the `strdup`?  function, if you don't have `strdup` on your platform write your own (google is your friend). 2. Don't hide pointers behind typedefs, it only adds confusion.

Comment: i tried using strdup and i get a segmentation fault thats because i dont allocate memory enough right, how can i change the allocations in the initialization so its good @Jabberwocky